# Remove Timestamp Prefix from Go Logger

Tags: go, logging, timestamp

I am utilizing Go Logger and a third party library called lumberjack for file rotation:

- https://golang.org/pkg/log/
- https://github.com/natefinch/lumberjack

Code Setting up the logger:

```
log.SetOutput(&lumberjack.Logger{
  Filename:   "/var/log/proxy.log",
  MaxSize:    1000, // megabytes
  MaxBackups: 3,
  MaxAge:     1, // days
  Compress:   true, // disabled by default
})
```

The logs I have are sensitive, so here is a hypothetical example of the output of a log:

```
 2018/02/05 19:00:08 "My log"
```

The logging schema for my company does not comply with having a timestamp in the front. I am gathering a different timestamp from other resources. I would like to remove the prefixed timestamp so that it only logs:

```
"My log"
```

I've looked through both links above, and looked through the source of the third party library lumberjack, and have not discovered a way to remove this. I saw the `SetPrefix()` funtion in the go log documentation. I tried doing the following to try and cancel the timestamp prefix, but it failed:

```
log.SetPrefix("")
```

Is there any obvious or not so obvious way to remove the timestamp?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [log.SetFlags](https://godoc.org/log#SetFlags) to remove the timestamp.

```
log.SetFlags(log.Flags() &^ (log.Ldate | log.Ltime))
```

The above removes the timestamp from whatever flags might be set.  To remove all flags, including the timestamp, use the following:

```
log.SetFlags(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Can you please explain how it removes the timestamp based on the parameters you sent to `log.SetFlags(int)`?

Comment: @FanusduToit  The expression `log.Flags() &^ (log.Ldate | log.Ltime)` clears the Ldata and Ltime flags from the  current flags using the bit clear operator.

Comment: It looks like you can also use `log.SetFlags(0)`